# Sort a square matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, matrix

I am solving a puzzle which is as follows.

There is a 5x5 matrix with one element as "-" and all others as whole numbers.
I can swap any element with the "-" straight(not diagonally).
Finally, I have to sort the matrix.

These are the steps I follow:

```
1) Receive user input for 5x5 matrix
2) Locate the position of "-"
3) Find the eligible candidates to be swapped with "-"
4) Apply some algorithm and find the most eligible candidate
5) Swap the element with "-"
6) Repeat the steps 3-5 until matrix is sorted
```

I have completed till step 3. However I have no idea what logic to be applied for step 4.
Can someone give some thoughts, how to find the most eligible candidate?

**Examples**

```
Input Matrix

17   7   9   18   3
15   11  1   12   14
2    -   4   21   24
5    19  6   18   8
10   13  16  19   20

Eligible candidates to swap with "-" are 11,2,4,19


Sorted matrix

1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  -
```

Answer (score 4):

this isn't the most easiest task. Here are two links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-puzzle#Solvability

http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ccalabro/essays/15_puzzle.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use some AI algorithm like A* with the Manhattan distance heuristic.

For A* algorithm read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)

For the Manhattan distance heuristic read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_function)